# .htaccess rewrite rules for multiple cases

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have very specific requirements for my url handling and I cannot figure out how to combine all of these.

If the user opens `http://example.com/abc123`, I need the following changes:

1. `http://` should become `https://`, then...
2. ...open `https://example.com/abc123.php` if file `abc123.php` exists
3. ...open `https://example.com/abc123/index.php` if directory `/abc123/` exists
4. ...open `https://example.com/index.php?abcdef` i.e. use `abc123` as parameter in normal `index.php`

For 2. - 4. I need the url in the address bar to remain `https://example.com/abc123`.

So far I have the following in my `.htaccess`, which I believe takes care of 1. and 2.:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for nice detailing. One question ultimately from url `http://example.com/abc123` to which url in backend you want to point to? Kindlyt do let us know.

Comment: Well it depends on what files and folders there are: if the following exists: https://example.com/abc123.php. If that doesn't exist but if the following exists: https://example.com/abc123/index.php. And finally, if neither exists: https://example.com/index.php?abcdef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an Apache server in front of me, but does this work for the last three?

```
# Look for URL.php as a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# Look for URL as a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/index.php [L]

# If the URL doesn't exist on disk in another way that Apache can
# figure out, forward it to index.hp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

EDIT: the following works well:

```
RewriteEngine On

# http:// -> https://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# -> https://example.com/abc123.php if that file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [END]

# -> index.php if /abc123.php and /abc123/ don't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [END]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. The following *almost* works. Except for example.com itself, which causes a "404 error - Object not found"
`RewriteEngine On` 

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [END]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/index.php [END]`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [END]`

(sry for the horrible formatting ^^)

Comment: Can you break each condition down and test each manually to see what needs to be tweaked?

Comment: Basically, all that's missing is `if example.com/abc123 is NOT a folder, redirect to example.com/index.php (without changing the url in the address bar, so I can still read abc123 with Javascript)`.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [END]` This unfortunately ALWAYS redirects to `example.com/index.php`, even if there is a directory called `/abc123`

Comment: Okay, the following works:

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [END]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [END]`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @TonaldDrump, I've marked this answer as community, so if you want to edit it with your answer, I don't get any rep but future readers will be able to learn from your experience.